# npm run dev error windows 10

Tags: javascript, nodejs, xampp, npm

Tengo errores con npm run dev, hice un npm rebuild, luego un npm install, para probar nuevamente con npm run dev, y me muestra estos errores:

```
# npm run dev

> pg@1.0.0 dev c:\xampp\htdocs\site
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --inline --hot

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'hard-source-webpack-plugin'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\xampp\htdocs\site\webpack.config.js:3:31)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pg@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --inline --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pg@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Desk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-12T04_14_16_402Z-debug.log
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Por google no encontré una solución que reparase el error, gracias.

Comment: vuelve a instalar webpack, y probalo si te sigue saliendo error, instala hard-source-webpack-plugin'

Comment: realizo las pruebas para ver si esta bien instalado que recomiendan aqui http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows y me funciona todo, igual requerirá una reinstalacion?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no encontró el módulo 'hard-source-webpack-plugin', comprueba que en tu archivo package.json tienes algo parecido a:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "hard-source-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.1"
  }
 "dependencies": {
    "hard-source-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.1"
  }
}
```

que aparezca ese 'hard-source-webpack-plugin en algunas de las dos líneas de dependencias (devDependencies o dependencies), si no apareciesen, simplemente en la raíz del proyecto(dónde tienes el package.json) escribe desde la línea de comandos:
    npm install --save hard-source-webpack-plugin